# How do I force group and permissions for created files inside a specific directory?

Tags: linux, file-permissions

For files created from the *testuser* account in the /var/www directory, I need they have *g+rwx* as permissions, and *www-data* as group.

How can I achieve this?

I'm creating the files via SSH.

Comment: **How** is your user creating files?  Via FTP `stor`/`appe` ?  Via HTTP `PUT`?  Through a shell account?  These details are important, because they greatly affect the possible answers, and need to be in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the input :), I'm creating everything via SSH.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

To set the group, give `/var/www` the **setgid** bit:

```
chgrp www-data /var/www
chmod g+s /var/www
```

To also adjust subdirectories: `find /var/www -type d -exec chmod g+s {} +`

This will make all newly created files inherit the parent directory's group, instead of the user's.

---

To set the default group permissions, you will have to use **ACLs**. Set a "default" ACL:

```
setfacl -m "default:group::rwx" /var/www
```

To also adjust subdirectories: `find /var/www -type d -exec setfacl -m d:g::rwx {} +`

Note: The file system must have ACL support enabled. Sometimes it is on by default; on *ext3* or *ext4* you might get "Operation not supported", in which case it must be enabled manually:

- For a currently mounted filesystem: `mount -o remount,acl /`
- Permanently – **one** of the methods below:

  - at fstab level: edit `/etc/fstab` to have `acl` in the options field
  - at filesystem level: `tune2fs -o acl /dev/diskname`

Comment: can't you get the subdirectories with chmod -R g+s /var/www? Doesn't seem like you should need the find command.

Comment: @bobpaul: No, because `chmod` would also get all files.

Comment: Note that some commands, in particular `install`, somehow manage to bypass directory default ACLs.

Comment: @grawity This is a really great answer and I am sure that there is a solution in there for my problem, but I can't figure it out. I have a `/var/www/html/projects` folder and when www-data creates a file it has `rw-rw-r` permissions but when I do something in console it creates a file with `rw-r--r`. How can I force new created files to always have `rw-rw-r` permissions?

Comment: @lewis4u: Globally or per-directory? The global (well, per-process) default permissions are controlled by `umask`. The per-directory default permissions are changeable using `setfacl` as in the main post.

Comment: I just played around a little bit more and it seems this does the trick for me:
`find projects -type d -exec chgrp www-data {} +` 
`find projects -type d -exec chmod g+s {} +` 
`sudo setfacl -R -d -m u::rw projects`

Comment: This was very helpful to me in August 2020.

Answer (score 5):

This might have gotten a few people stuck with 'grawity' answer on setgid, if the folder's group is different from your own you may need to run chmod as root but you won't get any error indicating you need to do this.

```
$ ls -ld dir
drwxrwxr-x 2 luke testgroup 4096 Mar  9 10:44 dir

$ chmod g+s dir                                    #no errors

$ ls -ld dir
drwxrwxr-x 2 luke testgroup 4096 Mar  9 10:44 dir  #but nothing changed

$ touch dir/nosudo && ls -l dir/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 luke luke 0 Mar  9 10:51 nosudo       #and the group is still wrong


$ sudo chmod g+s dir

$ ls -ld dir
drwxrwsr-x 2 luke testgroup 4096 Mar  9 10:44 dir  #the setgid bit is now on

$ touch dir/withsudo && ls -l dir/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 luke luke      0 Mar  9 10:51 nosudo
-rw-rw-r-- 1 luke testgroup 0 Mar  9 10:51 withsudo #and group is set
```

Comment: I was pulling my hair out before I ran across this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The group of the files being created by an user is the group of that user (in /etc/group). The permissions are controlled by the UMASK parameter
[see this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man2/umask.2.html)